# Retrieving failed jobs from a table with retry details (id and retry count)

Tags: sql, sql-server

My apologies for a non-intuitive thread title.

I have a table, `Jobs`, where each row represents a maintenance task performed by a computer program. It has this design:

```
CREATE TABLE Jobs (
    JobId bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
    Status int NOT NULL,
    OriginalJobId bigint NULL
)
```

When a Job is created/started, its row is added to the table and its status is `0`. When a job is completed its status is updated to `1` and when a job fails its status is updated to `2`. When a job fails, the job-manager will retry the job by inserting a new row into the Jobs table by duplicating the details of the failed job and reset the `Status` to `0` and use the original (failed) JobId in `OriginalJobId` for tracking purposes. If this re-attempt fails then it should be tried again up to 3 times, each subsequent retry will maintain the original `JobId` in the `OriginalJobId` column.

My problem is trying to formulate a query to get the current set of Jobs that have failed and get their retry count.

Here's a sample data in the table:

```
JobId | Status | OriginalJobId
    1,       1,           NULL    -- Successful initial job
    2,       0,           NULL    -- Pending initial job
    3,       2,           NULL    -- Failed initial job
    4,       1,              3    -- Successful retry of Job 3
    5,       2,           NULL    -- Failed initial job
    6,       2,              5    -- Failed retry 1 of Job 5
    7,       2,              5    -- Failed retry 2 of Job 5 -- should be tried again for 1 more time
    8,       2,           NULL    -- Failed initial job
    9,       2,              8    -- Failed retry 1 of Job 8
   10,       2,              8    -- Failed retry 2 of Job 8
   11,       2,              8    -- Failed retry 3 of Job 8 -- don't try again
   12,       2,           NULL    -- Failed initial job
```

My query needs to return this:

```
 JobId | RetryCount
     5,           2
    12,           0
```

Notice how Job `3` isn't included because its last retry succeeded (status `1`). Similarly Job `8` is excluded because the number of retries exceeds the limit of 3. Job `5` is included because it still failed and has had only 2 retries, and Job `12` is included and hasn't yet had any retries.

I'm thinking the solution would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    J1.JobId
FROM
    Jobs AS J1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Jobs AS J2 ON J1.JobId = J2.OriginalJobId
WHERE
    J1.Status = 2
```

...but I can't think of how to get the RetryCount data.

Here is a SQLFiddle I created for this problem, with one of the solutions below:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8765f

### Update

Here is an updated SQLFiddle that compares the 5 solutions provided so far (I added an extra `HAVING` clause to remove jobs that had more than 3 retries)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8765f/23

Performance-wise, I think GarethD's answer is the best as it has the simplest execution plan and tends to finish with the fastest time in SqlFiddle.

My production table has about 14,000,000 rows so obviously the results will be different there. I'll try each out in production and see which is the fastest then and choose an answer accordingly.

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following returns the result required:

```
SELECT  J1.JobId,
        Retries = COUNT(J2.JobId)
FROM    Jobs AS J1
        INNER JOIN Jobs AS J2 
            ON J1.JobId = J2.OriginalJobId
WHERE   J1.Status = 2
GROUP BY J1.JobId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN J2.Status = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

I have changed it to an `INNER` join so that only jobs that have been retried are included, although this could feasibly be changed back to a `LEFT` join to include failed jobs that have not been retried yet. I also added a `HAVING` clause to exclude any jobs that have not failed when they have been retried.

---

**EDIT**

As mentioned above, using `INNER JOIN` will mean that you only return jobs that have been retried, to get all failed jobs you need to use a `LEFT JOIN`, this will mean that retries are returned as failed jobs, so I have added an additional predicate `J1.OriginalJobId IS NULL` to ensure only the original jobs are returned:

```
SELECT  J1.JobId,
        Retries = COUNT(J2.JobId)
FROM    Jobs AS J1
        LEFT JOIN Jobs AS J2 
            ON J1.JobId = J2.OriginalJobId
WHERE   J1.Status = 2
AND     J1.OriginalJobId IS NULL
GROUP BY J1.JobId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN J2.Status = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd98c/1)**

Comment: @Tanner I have edited the answer to expand upon my original point of changing the inner join to a left join in order to include the jobs that have not been retried yet...

Comment: @Tanner yep, I forgot about that case when writing my question. My apologies :) I've added another case to the question, BTW. I'll evaluate your answer soon.

Comment: I noticed that this solution doesn't exclude Jobs that have a pending retry. I modified your query to add more `COUNT` values in the `SELECT` list which has a `CASE` predicate which only includes Jobs where all of the retries are `Status = 2 OR Status IS NULL`

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job. It does a COALESCE to combine `JobId` and `OriginalJobId`, gets the retry count by grouping them up then excluding any jobs that have a status of 1.

```
SELECT COALESCE(j.OriginalJobId, j.JobId) JobId, 
       COUNT(*)-1 RetryCount
FROM Jobs j
WHERE j.[Status] = 2
AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT 1
                FROM Jobs 
                WHERE COALESCE(Jobs.OriginalJobId, Jobs.JobId) = COALESCE(j.OriginalJobId, j.JobId)
                AND Jobs.[Status] = 1)
GROUP BY COALESCE(j.OriginalJobId, j.JobId), j.[Status]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the slightly more verbose CTE approach that I wrote that returns the results including the Jobs where the original job `status = 2` and there are no retries:

```
;WITH  cte AS (
       -- root level jobs that failed and did not have status of 1 after
       SELECT   j.JobId , j.OriginalJobId , 0 AS RetryCount
               FROM     dbo.Jobs j
               WHERE    j.OriginalJobId IS NULL AND j.Status = 2
                        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT OriginalJobId
                                         FROM   dbo.Jobs
                                         WHERE  Status = 1
                                                AND OriginalJobId = j.JobId )
       -- unioned with retries
       UNION ALL
       SELECT   j.JobId , j.OriginalJobId , 1 AS RetryCount
       FROM     dbo.Jobs j
       INNER JOIN cte ON cte.JobId = j.OriginalJobId
)
-- Group Jobs & Count retries 
SELECT  JobId , SUM(RetryCount) Retries
FROM    ( SELECT    JobId , cte.RetryCount
          FROM      cte
          WHERE     OriginalJobId IS NULL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    OriginalJobId AS JobId , cte.RetryCount
          FROM      cte
          WHERE     OriginalJobId IS NOT NULL
        ) t
GROUP BY JobId
```

Comment: Love a good CTE so +1 from me. But OP has changed his post slightly so this *almost* works :)

Comment: @DavidG ok I've tweaked it and got it working, but i'm pretty sure it's way more complex than it needs to be. Oh well, something for the OP to work from.

Answer (score 2):

What about this "Look ma'! No joins!" solution:

```
select coalesce(OriginalJobId, JobId) JobId, count(OriginalJobId) RetryCount
from Jobs
group by coalesce(OriginalJobId, JobId)
having count(case status when 1 then 1 end) = 0
and max(status) > 0
order by JobId;
```

Returns the desired result:

```
 JobId | RetryCount
    6,           3
   15,           0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do we need to perform a join, since the only thing we want is count OriginalJoibId occurences not having a '1'?

```
SELECT OriginalJobId, COUNT(*) As RetryCount
FROM Jobs
WHERE OriginalJobId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY OriginalJobId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

I think we can simply ignore all entries having NULL in OriginalJobId, and focus only on retrial records.

EDIT:

I hadn't noticed the second record added to the required output when I wrote my answer. The best I can do to mend it is the following rather ugly construct :=)

```
SELECT OriginalJobId, COUNT(*) As RetryCount
FROM Jobs
WHERE OriginalJobId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY OriginalJobId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT j.JobId, 0
FROM Jobs j
WHERE (Status = 2) AND (OriginalJobId IS NULL) AND 
      (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Jobs WHERE OriginalJobId = j.JobId))
```

Comment: This doesn't return the second row.

Comment: @Tanner When I wrote my answer I honestly wasn't aware of the edit.